# Case in where Clause to find String in Parameter

Tags: sql-server, string, parameters, case, where-clause

I have a table in my database tblCustomer, which has 8 boolean fields (MS01,MS02... MS08)
Using an SSRS report, I have a multi value parameter dropdown list that allows the selection of each of the 10 values
So if I select MS01 & MS05 from the list, the parameter @idSite will equal 'MS01','MS05'

'-1' = True

I want to select all records from tblCustomer where the selected parameter values are true

```
select idCustomer, MS01, MS02,MS03, MS04,MS05,MS06,MS07,MS08 from tblCustomer

WHERE     (tblCustomer.CustomerYN = '-1')
AND
CASE 
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS01%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS01=-1 
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS02%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS02=-1
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS03%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS03=-1
END as MailShot
```

I also tried using when the string was 'in' the pareameter

```
select idCustomer, MS01, MS02,MS03, MS04,MS05,MS06,MS07,MS08 from 
tblCustomer

WHERE     (tblCustomer.CustomerYN = '-1')
AND
CASE 
WHEN  'MS01' in @idSite THEN  tblCustomer.MS01=-1 
WHEN  'MS02' in @idSite THEN  tblCustomer.MS02=-1

END as MailShot
```

I thought I was close with the above, but no joy. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT

@idSite is SSRS multi value parameter dropdown list. 
It takes value idMailshot from the below table based on the section from the drop down

```
idMailShot  Location
MS01    Location1   
MS02    Location2     
MS03    Location3 
MS04    Location4  
MS05    Location5  
MS06    Location6     
MS07    Location7   
MS08    Location8   
MS09    Location9
```

So If i select Location1 & Location 2 from the drop down, "MS01,MS02" should be passed as @idSite
I want to

```
select idCustomer from tblCustomer where
tblCustomer.MS01 =-1 AND tblCustomer.MS02=-1
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample data and suggested output? Also. DECLARE @idSite ='MS01','MS02','MS03'; is not valid - is the input a comma delimited list?

Comment: Why not use `bit` to hold your flags / values `1` for true and `0` for false?  Why pass in an array of strings rather than having a `bit` parameter for each field?  NB: Your current code won't run since `DECLARE @idSite ='MS01','MS02','MS03';` is invalid / has no type.

Comment: Should it be: `declare @idSite table (MSFlag char(4)); insert @idSite (MSFlag) values ('MS01', 'MS02', 'MS03')`?

Comment: @idSite is SSRS multi value parameter dropdown list. 
It takes value idMailshot from the below table based on the section from the drop down  
idMailShot Location
MS01 Location1   
MS02 Location2     
MS03 Location3 
MS04 Location4  
MS05 Location5  
MS06 Location6     
MS07 Location7   
MS08 Location8   
MS09 Location9

Answer (score 3):

There is no such way to store multiple values in Sql Server variables like this:
`DECLARE @idSite ='MS01','MS02','MS03';`

But you can full fill multiple values in a **variable table** this way:

```
declare @idSites table
(
  idSite varchar(100)
)
insert into @idSites (idSite) 
select COLUMN_NAME from Information_schema.Columns 
where TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name' and TABLE_CATALOG = 'Database Name'
```

If you are getting a string that  like this `"MS01,MS02,MS03"`
then you need to write a function to generate a table based on `comma` separated values, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(8000) )
    RETURNS
        @returnList TABLE ([Param] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) 
        SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

        INSERT INTO @returnList
        SELECT @name

        SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
    END
    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT @stringToSplit
    RETURN
END
```

Then just use it like this:

```
declare @StringVariable varchar(255) = "MS01,MS02,MS03";
Select [param] from splitstring(@StringVariable)
```

Also your `WHERE` clause doesn't make much sense. I have written a test environment below, please see how i maintained `WHERE` clause there.

Below solution is with assumed data, you can copy paste it to `SQL Server` and execute. Hope it will help you achieve your desired requirement :).

```
--Declaring table with multi values
declare @idSites table
(
    idSite varchar(100)
)
insert into @idSites values ('MS01')
insert into @idSites values ('MS02')
insert into @idSites values ('MS03')

--Assuming a table with columns and values added in below CTE
;with cte as (
select 
-1 as MS01
,2 as MS02
,-1 as MS03
,-1 as CustomerYN
union all
Select 
 2 as MS01
,-1 as MS02
,0 as MS03
,0 as CustomerYN
)
--Finally The query part to fetch the data as per understood from your question.
select 
*
from cte
where cte.CustomerYN = -1
   AND(
        (cte.MS01 =  -1 AND 'MS01' = (Select idSite from @idSites where idSite = 'MS01'))
        OR (cte.MS02 =  -1 AND 'MS02' = (Select idSite from @idSites where idSite = 'MS02'))
        OR (cte.MS03 =  -1 AND 'MS03' = (Select idSite from @idSites where idSite = 'MS03'))
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` makes no sense:

```
WHERE     (tblCustomer.CustomerYN = '-1')
AND
CASE 
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS01%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS01=-1 
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS02%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS02=-1
WHEN  @idSite like '%MS03%' THEN  tblCustomer.MS03=-1
END as MailShot
```

Your `CASE` expression as a whole isn't a boolean expression, it's got boolean expressions inside the `THEN`; a `CASE` returns a scalar value not a boolean. You've also aliased your `CASE` in your `WHERE`. You don't alias expressions in your `WHERE`.

Rather than using a `CASE` expression (which would make your query non-SARGable), however, you would be far better using boolean logic:

```
WHERE tblCustomer.CustomerYN = -1 -- -1 is a int, pass it as one
  AND ((tblCustomer.MS01 = -1 AND @idSite like '%MS01%')
   OR  (tblCustomer.MS02 = -1 AND @idSite like '%MS02%')
   OR  (tblCustomer.MS03 = -1 AND @idSite like '%MS03%'))
```

*Note, if you are using a `CASE` expression inside a `WHERE` (although, like I said above, that would cause it to be non-SARGable) you need to return a scalar value and create a boolean expression. As a simple example:*

```
WHERE CASE @SomeID WHEN 1 THEN T.ColumnA
                   WHEN 2 THEN T.ColumnB
                   ELSE T.ColumnC
      END = 'Some Value'
```

*Notice that the `CASE` expression returns a scalar value (the value of either `ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, or `ColumnC`), and then that scalar value is compared to the literal string `'Some Value'`. You're boolean expression doesn't go in the `THEN`, it goes outside of the `CASE` expression.*

Comment: This is real close. Giving me correct figures for MS01 MS02 but all after that are wrong. Also;If i select multiple options, @idSite isn't handling as a comma separated list as i expected

Answer (score 0):

if u want to pass the values how you are doing. You need a split function. Because your value combo is not found. Your trying to value for column header value vs the value stored in the cell in this case.

```
DECLARE @idSite ='MS01','MS02','MS03';
```

Your alternate is to build a lookup table on the fly using a CTE and then dumping the data into temp table at the start of your report proc. Which will do a combo of 10 values and store them. And then you leverage this temp table on the fly in your filter clause.  Do keep in mind the 'join' condition (i.e. columns on which you will join back to this temp table from main table).